Как удалить текстовый канал через некоторое время после его создания discord.py
Мне нужно удалить текстовый канал спустя некоторое время после его создания командой
await categoty.create_text_channel(name=f'{channel}')

Как видно из документации, метод create_text_channel, который вы используете для создания канала, возвращает в качестве результата объект с типом TextChannel, то есть, обычный текстовый канал.

Запишите результат метода в переменную и делайте с объектом канала что хотите
channel = await categoty.create_text_channel(name=f'{channel}')
await channel.delete()


Смотрите, мне нужно чтобы именно при создании канала закладывался его "срок жизни".

@ЯковТерехов как вариант, просто вызовите delete с задержкой через asyncio.sleep

Добавил это в код, теперь выдает ошибку: Traceback (most recent call last): discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'asyncio' is not defined

Текст ошибки почитайте. Или переведите через переводчик. Библиотеку нужно подключить
